# Как поменять класс в выпадающем списке формы Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Здравствуйте.

Есть задача поменять класс в каждом элементе выпадающего списка формы.

```
class PortfolioItemForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = PortfolioItem
        fields = ['currency', 'color']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PortfolioItemForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['currency'].queryset = Currency.objects.all()
        self.fields['color'].queryset = Color.objects.all()
```

Класс можно поменять для всего инпута, при помощи `self.fields['color'].attrs['class'] = 'some class'`, но задача стоит поменять класс для каждого элемента в выпадаюзщем списке, который.

Например, каждому элементу выпадающего списка добавить `id` этого элемента из `queryset` в атрибут `class`. 
Надеюсь понятно объяснил.

Как это сделать ?

Comment: `queryset` не имеет CSS классов. Это python объект. Расскажите чего вы хотите добиться, уже исходя из этого вам помогут.

Comment: Не правильно выразился.
Я хочу добавлять в один из атрибутов для каждого элемента в выпадающем списке значение взятое из queryset,

Answer (score 2):

```
class PortfolioItemForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = PortfolioItem
        fields = ['currency', 'color']
        widgets = {
            'color': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'some-class'}),
        }
```

Comment: Нужно, чтобы класс был разным для каждого элемента в выпадающем списке.
Например, если это select с options, то должно быть <select><option class="1">some value</option></select>, где 1 - это id в class - это id из queryset.

Comment: Тогда либо [ручной рендеринг полей формы](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually), либо написание [своего виджета](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/widgets/#widget).